# Select and display date in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I am trying to write a code in Kotlin to select and display date. No idea whats wrong with my code. can some one sincerely help me fix the bug. I will be highly grateful. Thanks in advance.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)

    var c = Calendar.getInstance()
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        findViewById<Button>(R.id.done).setOnClickListener {
            addTopic(it)
            }
        fun updateDateInView() {
            val myFormat = "dd.MM.yyyy" // mention the format you need
            val sdf = SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.US)
            textView_date.text = sdf.format(c.time)
        }

        val dateSetListener =
            DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener { datePicker: DatePicker, year: Int, monthOfYear: Int, dayOfMonth: Int ->
                 fun onDateSet(
                   view: View,
                   year: Year,
                   month: Month,
                   dayofMonth: Month
               ) {
                     c.run {
                         set(Calendar.YEAR, Year)
                         set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear)
                         set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth)
                     }
                     updateDateInView()
               }
           }

            button_date!!.setOnClickListener(object : View.OnClickListener {
            override fun onClick(view: View) {
                DatePickerDialog(this@MainActivity, dateSetListener,
                    c.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                    c.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                    c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show()
            }

        })
}
```

Comment: How do you know it's wrong?  Do you get a compilation error, or runtime error message?  If so, please post that.  Otherwise, please describe what happens, and why that's wrong.

Comment: Hi Benjamin, Thanks for your response.I was able to get the error resolved. The code is running how, however, it only displays current date. Dont know why. Here is the updated code. Can you help. Thanks